# Third condition in MongoDB aggregation not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb

### Problem

I have a `$project` pipeline which has a `$filter` which has a `$cond`. When I have more than one comparison operator it stops working.

#### This is working

Only one comparison operator.

```
[
   {
      "$and":[
         {
            "$setIsSubset":[
               [
                  "$row.identifier"
               ],
               [
                  "tzi"
               ]
            ]
         },
         {
            "$not":{
               "$gt":[
                  "$row.value",
                  "1"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

#### This is not working anymore

Now two comparison operators.

```
[
   {
      "$and":[
         {
            "$setIsSubset":[
               [
                  "$row.identifier"
               ],
               [
                  "tzi"
               ]
            ]
         },
         {
            "$not":{
               "$gt":[
                  "$row.value",
                  "1"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "$not":{
               "$lt":[
                  "$row.value",
                  "10"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I can provide the whole query (which is very long) if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying

(NOT greater than 1) AND (NOT less than 10)

which is the same thing as saying

(less than or equal to 1) AND (greater than or equal to 10)

No number satisfies that condition.

Comment: I know right... we've all been there. Many times. :)

Comment: I wish you a nice and or a pleasant day ;)